# How to handle Register output in state machine with verilog

Tags: verilog, clock, register

Assuming I wan't to implement a state machine in verilog, where I have 1 output which is a register
So the output must be in sync with the input clock.
I know that the transitions between the machine states should be implemented via sequential block, for example:

```
always @ (posedge clock)
  if (state)
      state <= 1'b0;
  else
      state <= 1'b1;
```

If I want the output to be in sync with the clock, will implementing the output result via combinatorial will do? I mean:

```
always @ (state)
  if (state) 
      Out_Reg = a;
  else 
      Out_Reg = b;
```

Does this implementation still valid for Out_Reg to be a positive edge triggered register?

Or should I make assignment to Out_Reg in the sequential block for it to be a valid synced output register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably synthesize your design to be sure, but I expect that your example will result in `Out_Reg` being generated from combinatorial logic. It could more conventionally be expressed as

```
wire Out_Reg;
// ...
assign Out_Reg = state ? a : b;
```

If you want `Out_Reg` to be the output of a physical register (flip-flop), you could write

```
reg Out_Reg;
// ....
always @(posedge clock) begin
    Out_Reg <= state ? a : b;
end
```

But then, of course, the value of `Out_Reg` is delayed by one clock cycle relative to the state of `state`. If you need it to be in sync, you would need to duplicate the `state` logic so that `Out_Reg` anticipates what the next state of `state` will be. You could simplify this by using combinatorial logic to create a `next_state` signal:

```
wire next_state;
reg state, Out_Reg;

assign next_state = /* logic to determine next value of `state` */
always @(posedge clock)
    state <= next_state
// ...
always @(posedge clock)
    Out_Reg = next_state ? a : b;
```

However, you should also consider whether this is necessary. Does your downstream logic really care whether the output of this module is physically sourced from a register or from a combinatorial gate?